# Timing parallel timeout for process in Java

Tags: java, process, parallel-processing, timeout

I wanted to launch a bunch of process to work simultaneously - so i've created an array of process and the lunched them like this:

```
    Process[] p_ids= new Process[ids.length];
    int index = 0;
    //launching the processes
    for (int id: ids) {
        String runProcessCommand = createCommandForProcess();
        System.out.println(runProcessCommand);
        try {
            p_ids[index] = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runProcessCommand);
            index++;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
```

After that I wanted to wait for all of them to finish. So I took the same array of processes and iterate over all the process in it, each iteration I am waiting for the current iterated process to finish or wait for a specific time out to pass.

like this:

```
    for (Process p_id: p_ids) {
        try {
            //timeout for waiting a process
            p_id.waitFor(timeoutForSingleProcess, TimeUnit.HOURS);
            //error handling when reaching timeout
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("One of the process's execution time exceeded the timeout limit");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I want to give a total_time_out - meaning a fixed time out for each one of the processes.

saying I have process1, process2, process3. I want to give a timeout of 1 hour. If each one of the process (1,2 or 3) will take more then an hour to finish I want the timeout to kick in.

The problem in my code that the timeout is starting to count down the time - when it turn arrives in the loop (and not in the same time as the other process). i.e. if process1 takes 0.5 an hour and process 2 takes 1 hour - the two process will be launch at the same time *but* process 2 timeout will start counting down 0.5 hour after its lunch (because we waited 0.5 hour for process 1 before moving to process 2). that way the timeout that should have been activated - was ignored.

Is there any process pool or something like that which could help me?

Comment: You could use an `ExecutorService` and `.awaitTermination()` on it; if some processes are not finished you `.shutdownNow()` and you'll have a list of all tasks (processes) which have not finished at this point in time.